# webapp2 flash messages get lost during redirect_to

Tags: python, flash, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I'm using [coto boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/bp_includes/lib/basehandler.py), which extends the dispatch() method to start the session store and save all sessions at the end of a request, following [webapp2 doc](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html):

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

@webapp2.cached_property
def messages(self):
    return self.session.get_flashes(key='_messages')

def add_message(self, message, level=None):
    self.session.add_flash(message, level, key='_messages')
```

My problem is that flash messages get lost during a redirect_to. 
This line resets self.session and looses the flash messages:

```
self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I, too, found that redirect_to loses flash messages on the way. My quick fix was to use

```
self.redirect(self.request.referer)
```

all is good ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I would like to add an answer:

`redirect_to()` and `redirect()` do not completely halt code execution for the current request (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231880/how-to-stop-execution-after-self-redirect) and [here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect) for reference). It's mostly unnoticeable but the response for that request is still processed, even though the user has been redirected and is shown the new response. I was able to fix this by adding a `return` underneath the redirect.

```
self.add_message('Your changes have been saved.', 'info')
self.redirect_to('home')
return
```

`redirect_to()` and `redirect()` also support an `abort` parameter, which raises an exception to perform the redirect. I personally just use `return` instead.